# Apache Velocity Escape Dot Character

Tags: java, templates, escaping, velocity

I started looking into Velocity for templating, however I can't seem to escape the dot character after a variable name. Below is the template I have.

```
## function.vm
void functionA() {
    int minimum_value = $class_name.MIN_VALUE;
    int maximum_value = $class_name.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Where `$class_name` is a variable that I set in the `VelocityContext` as below.

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
velocityContext.put("class_name", "Short");
```

However, this would output the below, no change.

```
void functionA() {
    int minimum_value = $class_name.MIN_VALUE;
    int maximum_value = $class_name.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Adding a back-slash before the dot character `$class_name\.MIN_VALUE` would replace the variable, but it would also print the back-slash as well, as below.

```
void functionA() {
    int minimum_value = Short\.MIN_VALUE;
    int maximum_value = Short\.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Is escaping not done with a back-slash? I found multiple answers saying it should be with a back-slash, others with using `$esc.java()` but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use curly-braces around `class_name` like:

```
## function.vm
void functionA() {
    int minimum_value = ${class_name}.MIN_VALUE;
    int maximum_value = ${class_name}.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

This generates the below output:

```
void functionA() {
    int minimum_value = Short.MIN_VALUE;
    int maximum_value = Short.MAX_VALUE;
}
```